# Gnome-Disk-Utility : How to Launch It?

Tags: gnome

I had gnome-disks installed already.
i needed to install the one from source code however.

i downloaded and configured it and installed it.

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

when i run "gnome-disks" it launches the old version

Answer (score 0):

run sudo apt-get remove gnomedisk (not positive on the name because i don't use ubuntu i use arch) then launch it again.